# Finding a special kind of continuous map on finite dimensional Hilbert Space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space,  $B:=\{x∈H:∥x∥≤1\}$ be its unit ball

Does there exist a continuous map $f:H→H$ such that $f(f(x))=x , ∀x∈H$, $f$ has no fixed points, and $f(B)$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the dimension of the Hilbertspace is finite dimensional we have that $B$ is compact. Since $f$ is continuous $f(B)$ will always be bounded.

Comment: What if we drop the condition that the image of B is unbounded?

Comment: In that case the Brouwer fixed point theorem might provide the answer. However, one needs to check that $f:B\to B$. This could be shown using the continuity and that $f^2=id$. But any other suggestions are appreciated